# Draw Views with Round Corners in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse RCP application the editor is drawn with round corners at the top. My views however have sharp corners at the top of the view frame. If you look at the views in the Eclipse IDE, you will notice that they all have round corners at the top. The round corners are drawn if the view title is visible. I don't want to display the view title. So I wondered if it is possible to draw an untitled view with round corners.

P.S.: I have also considered drawing a round rectangle in the background of the view. The problem with that solution is that every view is surrounded by a 1px dark gray borderline and that borderline would still have sharp corners.

Answer (score 0):

put the following line to your ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor (eg. to public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer))

```
PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_TRADITIONAL_STYLE_TABS, false);
```

Comment: Well this would not help, because it will only change the look of the tabs. If you have view with no title at the top, you got no tabs at the top. Which means you will end up with the same sharp corners as before.